# With select2.js with a placeholder I can't select the first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a `<select>` list that I'm styling with select2.js.  For the most part everything works, however, when a placeholder is used, a user drops down the list, and then tries to select the first item in the list they are not able to.  If the user selects any item other than the first item and then goes back and selects the first item that works fine.  It's as if the first item is already selected (it is highlighted already) but not really (since the value of the list is empty and the placeholder is displayed).

HTML

```
    <select id="selectBox"></select>
```

Binding JS

```
$("#selectBox").select2({
    placeholder: "Select an item",
    width: '267px' });
```

Populate JS

```
var showThings = function() {

    var $selectBox = $('#selectBox');

    $selectBox.empty();

    blah.executeRequest('getThings', function(result) {

            $(result.sort(SortByName)).each(function(index, user) {

                var asOption = [];

                asOption.push('<option value ="' + user['id'] + '">' +
                    user['name'] + '</option>');


                if (asOption.length > 0) {
                    $selectBox.append(asOption.join('\n'));
                }
            });
        }
    );
};
```

The "executeRequest" is just grabbing data from some Java code, populating the list works fine, but figured I'd include the code so that it could be seen where the list data is coming from.

If anyone has any ideas on this, or has experienced it and knows how to fix it, I'd be most appreciative.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before pushing "real" values, try adding an empty `<option></option>` to the beginning of your `select` element.

**Update:** I wrote a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jyyerjxx/) for you.

Comment: Tried this, no luck, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Turned out the reason it didn't work was another issue, the empty option did work after all.  Thanks!